# JSP on tomcat https port displaying incorrectly

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, https, ec2-ami

I have a tomcat 8 server with http and https ports. All the jsp files run fine on http, but on https the jsp tags are getting output to the page and I'm seeing something like this.

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%> <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
...
```

I'm not sure what the root cause of the problem is, although it seems like it's a tomcat configuration problem. I've been looking through my tomcat config files in case there's something out of place, but it seems mostly fine from what I can tell. What might be the issue?

The jsp tags are well formed. The https port is hooked up to an elastic load balancer, which I'm pretty sure is setup correctly at this point.

For what it's worth, here's what I've got for the connectors in my server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" proxyPort="80" proxyName="www.pckit.org"
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000" />

<Connector port="443" proxyPort="443"
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"/>

 <Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

Here's the jsp servlet in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I also found this output in the catalina log files, which might be related.

```
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.825 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"] 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.826 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]  java.net.SocketException: Permission denied     at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.828 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484) Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)  ... 12 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)     ... 13 more

28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.835 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.836 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.839 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 948 ms 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.884 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina     
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.884 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:55.898 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.316 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.373 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/host-manager has finished in 1,474 ms 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.379 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples 28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.382 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'allowLinking' to 'true' did not find a matching property. 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.415 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1091)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1830)     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:304)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:162)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1890)    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)     ... 10 more

28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.416 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1091)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1830)     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.419 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples has finished in 40 ms 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.419 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/manager 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.733 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.735 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/manager has finished in 316 ms 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:57.735 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT2 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.063 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.065 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT2 has finished in 330 ms 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.065 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/sample 
28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.336 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
 28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.340 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/sample has finished in 275 ms 
 28-Jun-2016 02:49:58.340 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT 
 28-Jun-2016 02:49:59.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
 28-Jun-2016 02:49:59.700 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,360 ms 
 28-Jun-2016 02:49:59.703 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/docs 
 28-Jun-2016 02:50:00.222 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
 28-Jun-2016 02:50:00.224 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/docs has finished in 521 ms 
 28-Jun-2016 02:50:00.238 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 
 28-Jun-2016 02:50:00.255 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 
 28-Jun-2016 02:50:00.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4422 ms 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:30.551 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/ROOT2] 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:30.551 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ROOT2] has started 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.079 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.088 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ROOT2] is completed 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.088 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/host-manager] 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.089 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/host-manager] has started 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.415 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/host-manager] is completed 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.415 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/docs] 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.415 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/docs] has started 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.644 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/docs] is completed 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.647 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [] 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:31.647 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [] has started 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.222 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [] is completed 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.223 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/examples] 
 28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.246 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Error during context [/examples] restart  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1380)  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1344)  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1577)   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:284)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1141)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:304)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:162)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1890)    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)     at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)     ... 11 more

28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.259 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/manager] 
28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.259 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/manager] has started 
28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/manager] is completed 
28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context [/sample] 
28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.469 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/sample] has started 
28-Jun-2016 03:28:32.876 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/sample] is completed
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can not bind the port (443) because of permission. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/610117/failed-to-bind-to-0-0-0-0443